# Install from Network in HP UX

Tags: networking, installation, hp-ux

I wonder if its possible to install a HP UX server from network, but using a "installation server (or depot)" that is not a HP UX machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HP9000 and HP Integrity machines can netboot only from an Ignite server. Ignite/UX only run on HP-UX. So, you cannot install HP-UX from non-HP-UX system.

Answer (score 1):

You can install a HP-UX server booting the server from network using a Ignite Server as the other people answered.
You can use a Ignite Server installed on a linux machine, in this case it's called Ignite-LUX.
Here http://bizsupport2.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02491013/c02491013.pdf you have a whitepaper describing the configuration of a Ignite-LUX server on linux and the requirements of this software.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to craft something using linux and NFS but as far as I know, the perferred method of using Ignite, is only supported on the HP-UX platform.